# Update own created Cocoa pods iOS Objective C

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have successfully created own Cocoa pods using this [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TcSqF_vnvD0), now i need to update that Cocoa pods i have created.How can i do that.? Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks

Comment: just create new version of that, create new tag, and push to trunk, thats all

Comment: @Tj3n so i need to follow whole process ,by skipping register part. !?